# Linux /dev/input/event*: lost mouse movement events

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a simple code that in theory should track the mouse position using global pixel coordinates based on display width/height.

The application creates a window (1x1 pixel at top left display corner) only for catching "ok" keyboard buttons press to stop it and to move mouse at (0, 0) when application starts. So "write" *ok* in order to close the application!

When I move the mouse from left to right (or top/bottom) I always obtain a different value when I reach the edge of the screen. My screen is set at 1920x1080 but never reach 1920 when I'm on the right edge. Maybe a normalization problem but this is not the point.

**The problem is that if I move the mouse to the left edge of the screen when I'm at right edge I can't reach 0 and when I go right again I don't reach the same value as before.**

It seems that some events are lost and the behaviour changes if I move the mouse with higher acceleration.

This is a working code, you only have to change the variable `mouseID` with your based on output from `ls -lh /dev/input/by-id` command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/usr/include/linux/input.h"
#include <poll.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "SDL.h"


typedef struct connectedMouseInfoStruct
{
    struct pollfd fileDescriptors[1];
    char devInputStream[96];
    unsigned char eventsBuffer[640000];
    short type;
    short code;
    int value;
    int currX;
    int currY;
    int prevX;
    int prevY;
}connectedMouseInfo;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *mouseID = "usb-PixArt_Microsoft_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse";
    int exit = 0;
    int firstKey = 0;
    char *inputEvent = "/dev/input/by-id/";
    connectedMouseInfo connectedMouse = {0};
    int dx = 0;
    int dy = 0;
    SDL_Event events;
    const Uint8 *keyboardState = NULL;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int bufferPosition;

    // Start
    SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_DisplayMode currentVideoMode;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &currentVideoMode);
    SDL_Window* gameWindow = NULL;

    gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
                "MouseEvents",
                0,
                0,
                1,
                1,
                SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN);

    strcat(connectedMouse.devInputStream, inputEvent);
    strcat(connectedMouse.devInputStream, mouseID);

    connectedMouse.fileDescriptors[0].fd = open(connectedMouse.devInputStream, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    connectedMouse.fileDescriptors[0].events = POLLIN;

    SDL_WarpMouseGlobal(0, 0);

    while (!exit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&events))
        {
            keyboardState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

            if (events.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                if (events.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_O)
                {
                    firstKey = 1;
                }
            }

            if (firstKey && events.key.keysym.scancode == SDL_SCANCODE_K)
            {
                exit = 1;
            }
        }

        poll(&connectedMouse.fileDescriptors[0], 1, 0);

        if (connectedMouse.fileDescriptors[0].revents == POLLIN)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            bytesRead = read(connectedMouse.fileDescriptors[0].fd, connectedMouse.eventsBuffer, 640000);

            if (bytesRead == -1)
                printf("Read error!!!\n");
            else if ((bytesRead % sizeof(struct input_event)) != 0)
                printf("Incomplete packet!!!\n");
            else
            {
                printf("Read Bytes: %d\n", bytesRead);

                for (bufferPosition = 0; bufferPosition < bytesRead; bufferPosition += sizeof(struct input_event))
                {
                    memcpy(&connectedMouse.type, &connectedMouse.eventsBuffer[bufferPosition + sizeof(struct input_event) - 8], 2);
                    memcpy(&connectedMouse.code, &connectedMouse.eventsBuffer[bufferPosition + sizeof(struct input_event) - 6], 2);
                    memcpy(&connectedMouse.value, &connectedMouse.eventsBuffer[bufferPosition + sizeof(struct input_event) - 4], 4);

                    if (connectedMouse.type == EV_REL)
                    {
                        if (connectedMouse.code == REL_X)
                        {
                            connectedMouse.currX += connectedMouse.value;
                        }
                        else if (connectedMouse.code == REL_Y)
                        {
                            connectedMouse.currY += connectedMouse.value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (connectedMouse.currX > currentVideoMode.w - 1)
            connectedMouse.currX = currentVideoMode.w - 1;
        else if (connectedMouse.currX < 0)
            connectedMouse.currX = 0;

        if (connectedMouse.currY > currentVideoMode.h - 1)
            connectedMouse.currY = currentVideoMode.h - 1;
        else if (connectedMouse.currY < 0)
            connectedMouse.currY = 0;

        dx = connectedMouse.currX - connectedMouse.prevX;
        dy = connectedMouse.currY - connectedMouse.prevY;

        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0)
        {
            printf("Display X: %d\n", connectedMouse.currX);
            printf("Display Y: %d\n", connectedMouse.currY);
            printf("Delta X: %d\n", dx);
            printf("Delta Y: %d\n", dy);
            printf("\n");
        }

        connectedMouse.prevX = connectedMouse.currX;
        connectedMouse.prevY = connectedMouse.currY;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that your `read` call doesn't return a complete event sometimes? Idk if there's any guarantee that it would not return 24 bytes for some reason, and your code doesn't check that.

Comment: Updated code, added check, no read error detected. I also added EV_SYN events but nothing is changed. I read 16 Bytes, not 24, timestamp is composed by 2 `long int` and on my system they are 4 Bytes each

Comment: Reading an incomplete event is not the same thing as having or reporting a read error.  I am uncertain whether it is possible in practice to read a partial event from the device in question, but for robustness, code using `read()` and `write()` should make as few assumptions as possible.  The test in your `for` loop should be `bufferPosition + 16 <= bytesRead`, and if `bufferPosition < bytesRead` after the loop terminates then you need to account for the left-over partial event -- probably move it to the beginning of the buffer and start the next read at the following position.

Comment: Another possibility to consider is that another process may be consuming some of the mouse events.

Comment: @Francesco Yeah.. that's not what I said. Your code counts on multitudes of 16 bytes to be returned. I checked the return value from `read` and got a lot of 72 byte reads.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As you see in the code, buffer has size of 640000 Bytes but when I move the mouse I only get a max of 48 Bytes read. The for loop is ok, if I use <= I'll go over the buffer in the next loop. What other process could steal events?

Comment: @EmanuelP could you explain better?

Comment: @Francesco, the available space in the buffer has little to do with it.  It is potentially unsafe to assume that your program will always read multiples of 16 bytes, and if it should successfully perform a read with a byte count that is not divisible by 16 then your code will erroneously interpret the partial event at the end as a complete event, and will also fall out of register with the event source.  It is plausible to think that it could come back into register after some future read, but the events read up to that point will all be misinterpreted because of the registry problem.

Comment: @Francesco I mean sometimes it reads 72 bytes. I don't know the details of the event format, but obviously your code then discards some of those bytes because it loops over 16 bytes at a time.

Comment: Added a control of packet size, never catch an incomplete packet, always multiple of 16 during mouse movent from left to right

Comment: @Francesco I see. It depends on the architecture. See [https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L28](uapi/linux/input.h). You already include it, might as well use `struct input_event` instead of hardcoded offsets.

Comment: @EmanuelP the OP code is only an example. I'll add the size of the struct but at the moment we don't clarify why I lose some events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: if we set a flat profile for pointer acceleration the coordinates shown by the code exactly match the display width/height. I tried to move the pointer over a well defined pixel on my Desktop background and I always receive the same value.

So ***the problem was the mouse acceleration profile***

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you are actually losing mouse events. The position of the cursor on the screen just doesn't match the position you keep track of because of [mouse acceleration](https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/PointerAcceleration/) by the X server. If you turn that off, you will notice the mouse moves very slowly, and the values in your code will increase rapidly. So much so, that you will only cover a portion of the screen - but consistently. This is because the coordinate space is larger than your screen resolution.

Furthermore, you should not adjust the value on receiving an `EV_SYN` event. See the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/event-codes.html).

Comment: The code matches the pointer coordinates if I set `flat` profile for mouse acceleration. It doesn't move slow and the screen range is perfectly covered by the code. So it is not true that coordinate space is larger than screen resolution. Yes, `EV_SYN` is not necessary but it doesn't introduce any error because value is always `0`. Thanks for the tip on mouse acceleration

Comment: @Francesco Oh, okay. Then you should should keep in mind that on some machines this is the case. In my case, it covers about 1/4 of the screen.

Comment: Good to know it! You have some kind of Dekstop scaling? The application will run on a machine without X11 server in a fullscreen SDL window

Comment: @Francesco Actually, I think it may have to do with setting a "flat" profile while I [completely disabled it](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration#Disabling_mouse_acceleration)